# Combining Cypher Query results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is my query in Cypher...

```
START n=node(127) 
MATCH(n)-[:friends]->(x) 
WITH n, collect(distinct x) as friends 
MATCH(n)-[:outer_only_friends]->(y) 
RETURN friends, collect(distinct y) as outer
```

I'm trying to add the friends to the outer collection and return a collection of both inside of the query. This way I can use LIMIT and SKIP within the query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Chris,
this was answered on the ML, http://groups.google.com/group/neo4j/browse_thread/thread/56ecfef3130f2d92 ?

Comment: Thanks Peter. I've got the combining working. I'm just trying to build in the FILTER and I think I've got the syntax working but the combination returns a Scala object type and won't filter. I mentioned this on the Google Group.